# Cancel the loop when the if condition is not true

Tags: c, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to write a program that does Run-Length-Encoding. I wrote the program but I want to cancel the entire loop when there is a non-alphabet character in input. I mean, it should give an output like "The input is not valid!".

I tried several if conditions but every time it encodes the alphabet characters till the non-alphabet character, and then skip that character and continue to encode. Where and how should I put the if statement?

```
int main() {

  int i, txtLen=0, count;
  char text[100];

  printf("Please enter a text to RLE:\n");
  scanf("%s", text);

  while (text[i] != '\0') {
    txtLen++;
    i++;
  }

  for (i=0; i<txtLen; i++) {

    printf("%c", text[i]);
    count = 1;

    while (text[i+1] == text[i]){
      count++;
      i++;
    }

    if (count != 1) {
      printf("%d", count);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When I tried to put if statements, the input and output were like that:

**Input:** aa?aaabbb

**Output:** a2a3b3

Please do not give any suggestions or comments for other parts of my code.

Comment: Use a `break` statement to break out of a loop.

Comment: FYI, you can use `strlen()` to get the length instead of writing your own loop.

Comment: Show how you tried to add `if` statements, we're not going to write it for you.

Comment: Make sure you break out of the outer loop, not the inner loop.

Comment: `isalpha` is our friend and do to the test on one of your loop,

Comment: You can skip getting the length altogether: `for (i = 0; txt[i]; i++)  {`

Comment: Also, your inner `while` loop should check for end of string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main(void) {
  int i, txtLen=0, count;
  char text[100];

  printf("Please enter a text to RLE:\n");
  scanf("%s", text);

  while (text[i] != '\0') {
// check if the value of each char if it is within the alphabetical range of char
    if((text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z') || (text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z')) {
      printf("False Format\n");
      break;
    }
    txtLen++;
    i++;
  }

  for (i=0; i<txtLen; i++) {

    printf("%c", text[i]);
    count = 1;

    while (text[i+1] == text[i]){
      count++;
      i++;
    }

    if (count != 1) {
      printf("%d", count);
    }
  }  
 
  return 0;
}
```